# Indirectly updating state through a class function

Tags: react-native

I have a class, Person, with a function setName and getName.

```
var person = new Person("Johnny");
this.setState({personObj: person})
```

if I call this.state.personObj.getName(); I get Johnny as expected.

I know you aren't supposed to directly update state EG `this.state.name = 'Johnny'`

But is it bad to use a class function call to update a property in a class like

```
this.state.personObj.setName("Joe");
```

Seems like a grey area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you can update that instance of the object through functions, it doesn't help/affect the components state unless you call  this.setState. You can create a new state object from previous state and then use `this.setState`.  You will have to  invoke `this.setState` for the component to take the new state.